# Mismatch when extracting specific frames from video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I extracted all frames in a video using `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 test_3/0%d.jpg`.

Then I tried to extract specific frames using `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vframes 1 -vf "fps=24,select=eq(n\,221)" x.jpg`.

But I get a different frame then the one extracted in the first command.

I used the same fps as ffmpeg printed in the first command in the output info:

```
Output #0, image2, to 'x.jpg':
  Metadata:
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
```

Why is there a mismatch in the frames? 
How can I extract only specific frames, that will be the same to the first command?

Comment: VLC does that very well: https://otechworld.com/extract-frames-from-video/

Comment: I'm doing this as part of a script, so I prefer to use commandline applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image2 muxer is a constant frame rate muxer, so ffmpeg will duplicate frames if your source is variable frame rate. To ensure a 1:1 correspondence between frames and images, set `-vsync 0`

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vsync 0 test_3/0%d.jpg
```

Then to extract a particular frame,

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vframes 1 -vf "select=eq(n\,221)" -vsync 0 x.jpg
```